# Change default application - Button grayed out?

Tags: pdf, pcmanfm

When trying to change the default application for PDFs to "evince" in PcManFM-QT (version 0.14.1), I'm getting the problem that the "OK" button is grayed out.

[image]

How can I change the default application for PDFs to Evince anyway? Evince ist installed (can be used from the terminal), <strike>but does not show up in the "Installed Applications" list in the other register panel</strike> and shows up under the name "Document Viewer" in the applications pane.

Comment: Are you sure `evince` doesn't show up in Office applications (it's full name is 'Document Viewer', like `nautilus` shows up as 'Files')  *It does for my `pcmanfm-qt` (version 0.14.1)*

Comment: @guiverc You are right. There is a "Document Viewer" entry. I'll try that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNOME programs show up with their with the names shown in their respective .desktop files, ie. `nautilus` shows as "Files", `evince` as "Document Viewer" etc...

The following menu is how it displays on my system (same `pcmanfm-qt` version 0.14.1)

[image]

Comment: You didn't specify a release (19.04?), I'm running Lubuntu 19.10, but the version of `pcmanfm-qt` is identical.

Comment: While this solves my problem (thank you, I accepted this!), it doesn't actually answer why the "OK" button is grayed out.

Comment: It isn't grayed out for me. My system is Lubuntu 19.04. I can enter `evince %f` and provide "EVINCE" as the application name without any problems. It's difficult to say why you're facing this issue.

Comment: One possibility with new users is that some of *their* files/folders get owned by root through overuse of *sudo*. Do you get a lot of results when you run `find . '!' -user $USER -ls` in a terminal?

Comment: @DKBose Very little turns up. One directory with a chroot environment for some tests of untrusted source code and files in a few folders for libraries that I compiled and that had to be installed with "sudo make install" to copy them to "/usr/local/..." - that's it for the root-owned files in my home directory.